# How to use Identifiable in a ForEach loop

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to iterate through an array of objects. This object is conforming to the Identifiable protocol. When using a `ForEach` loop, I get the following error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

I've included the block of code that is throwing the error. The error is specifically underlining `\.name`. Am I missing something?

Another note: This code worked in Xcode 11 Beta 2 but broke in Xcode 11 Beta 3...

```swift
struct ItemRow : View {

    var categoryName:String
    var items:[Item]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.categoryName)
                .font(.title)

            ScrollView(showsHorizontalIndicator: false) {
                HStack (alignment: .top){
                    ForEach (self.items.identified(by: \.name)) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetail(item: item)) {
                            ItemView(item: item)
                                .frame(width:300)
                                .padding(.trailing, 30)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Identifiable Object:

```swift
struct Item:Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var category:Category
    var description:String
}
```

(This code has been abstracted)

Comment: Your code compiles just fine, but you left a lot of code out of your example, so I had to create the missing parts myself. Please include more code, specially your Identifiable type. And a little bit of more context. Otherwise it is impossible to help you.

Comment: @kontiki Thanks for the feedback. I added my Identifiable type. What kind of other context are you looking for? I'm trying to get better at asking questions so please let me know.

Comment: With more context I mean more of the code that surrounds the ForEach. However, with the new information you added I spotted a problem. Let me post it into an answer.

Comment: I posted an answer indicating some potential issues. Also, since you ask, to write better questions, please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @kontiki Thank you! I think an underlying issue is me not understanding the problem enough to ask about it in the first place. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you need to know, is that when building views, compile errors can be very misleading. An error may show at the bottom of your code, but the cause may be at the top. I expect this will be fixed sometime in the future, but for the time being, you need to be careful.

Your code compiles just fine. Because of what I said about misleading errors, one *brute* but effective technique to debug the problem, is to start commenting bits of code until the error goes away. This will let pin point where the root of the problem may be.

A good way of updating your question is including enough code, so that people can reproduce the problem just by copy and paste into their own Xcode. It may be a lot of work for you, but I found that most of the time, you understand the problem during that process and you may not even need to post the question in the first place. Reducing an issue to its minimum expression, is also a great way of understading/fixing a problem.

### UPDATE

Since you added more code, the error is showing where you would have not expected:

The ScrollView initialiser you were using, was deprecated. It now looks like this:

```swift
   ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false)
```

Also something that may potentially be a problem. You are using:

```swift
self.items.identified(by: \.name)
```

But don't you mean:

```swift
self.items.identified(by: \.id)
```

If so, then you do not need to use identified, since `Item` is already `Identifiable` and as such, it is already identified by id.

```swift
self.items
```

Comment: Good catch. That was my mistake when abstracting my code. That is supposed to be a view. I apologize. Thank you for catching that. I've updated the post.

Comment: I added some tips to my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer to add yet another tip about your use of `identifiable`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually with the following line:

`ScrollView(showsHorizontalIndicator: false)`

ScrollView doesn't work like that anymore in Beta 3. The arguments now look something like this:

`ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false)`

That will give you a horizontal scrolling view and will not show the scrolling indicators.